# Portable LAMP or XAMPP for Linux

Tags: linux, web-server, portable

Is there a portable version of LAMP or XAMPP for Linux? Or anything similar? I'm trying to find something I can run off a USB flash drive for development and testing between various machines.

Comment: (for Windows: http://portableapps.com/apps/development/xampp)

Comment: I'm well aware that this and many other solutions exist on Windows. However, I'm asking specifically for Linux because I cannot find anything that precompiles the software with statically linked libraries so it can be run as a portable installation off a USB drive.

Comment: Sure, just added the comment for people curious about Windows.

Comment: [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) can help you manage development environments in simple folders. It uses  virtualisation to run a guest OS. However, it is probably not portable and not very fast when run from USB flash drives (at least from older ones).

Comment: Also know about Vagrant, Docker, and other virtualization options. None are portable so they are all a no go.

Comment: I would suspect *true* portability in linux would be tricky, since you'd need to worry about distro and version compatability.

Comment: If you cannot find anything better: what about a "simple VM" with VirtualBox? Should be possible to put that on a stick (the VM I mean). Then you could run it even from a Mac or Windows machine if needed. Plenty of "minimalist distributions" available to cover that.

Comment: That would still require the host machine to have the VM software installed, which in my case is not something I have privilege to do on all the machines I need to work on. Hence why I shot down the Vagrant suggestion above.

@Journeyman Geek - Portability in Linux is entirely possible so long as the software statically links and distributes any required external libraries with their binary. The problem is that this runs counter to UNIX philosophy and is rarely done (as opposed to Windows where this is common practice). Hence why I am having such a hard time finding a solution to my question.

Comment: Portableapp xampp + WINE